# Trouble sending various queries into proper rows for set times

Tags: php, mysql

sorry about the title, i really did not know what I should call it, but hopefully you will be able to aid me with my script.

What I am trying to achieve (with my less than 5 hour total experience with any sort of "programming", hence the horrid coding) is to send one query X times, and then put a new query into those newly created rows.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) { // IF LOGGED IN

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT max(ordrenr) FROM antalstabel") or die(mysql_error());
$maxordrenr = mysql_query($sql);
$nextnumber = $maxordrenr + 1;
$maxplusantal = $maxordrenr + $antal;
$antal = count($items); // COUNTS DIFFERENT ITEMS IN CART.

for ($i = $maxordrenr; $i <= $maxplusantal; $i++) {

    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO antalstabel (ordrenr) VALUES ('$nextnumber')") or die(mysql_error());

}   

}
```

This is my first query, what this does (or what I want it to do) is to get the max ID of the table "antalstabel" add +1 and then count a certain amount up which is defined as $items untill it has executed X rows.

My first issue here, is the fact that my table consists of two key primaries, so returning a query like this would result in an error since after one return the two rows would be identical and will not execute.

The second issue is the fact that the next value in the table should not be inserted X times after each other, but rather be certain IDs added in afterwards.

What I am trying to achieve ultimately (not only by this script, but this is the current issue) is something like this:

```
ordrenr(key)varenr(key) antal
1           3           1
1           2           2
2           1           4
3           1           1
3           2           1
3           3           1
```

Does this make any sense whatsoever for anyone and can anyone tell me whether my method of doing this is jsut hopeless or have some better ideas for me to use as execution for ending up with something like this?

Should I not use primary keys or how does this work?

Thank you for even taking the time to read this :)

-Victor

EDIT for future:

changed script to this for it to work:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) { // IF LOGGED IN

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM antalstabel ORDER BY ordrenr DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
$maxordrenr = $row['ordrenr'];
$nextnumber = $maxordrenr + 1;
$maxplusantal = $maxordrenr + $antal;
$antal = count($items); // COUNTS DIFFERENT ITEMS IN CART.

for ($i = $maxordrenr; $i <= $maxplusantal; $i++) {

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO antalstabel (ordrenr, varenr) VALUES ('$nextnumber','1236')") or die(mysql_error());
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
$maxordrenr = mysql_query($sql);
```

should be

```
$maxordrenr = mysql_result($sql,0);
```

Comment: Currently im getting this error:
mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in...
This means that there is an issue with the query itself, right?

EDIT: Echoing the query, im getting this: "Resource id #6" - there are no number 6 in any of my tables (namely the ones called for), or nothing that comes even close to, why does this happen?

Comment: RE: I fixed it by changing the whole script, I watched it, i understand now, thank you a lot.